# Spark: explode function being extremely slow and consumes high CPU

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running my spark application on Apache Zeppelin on Amazon EMR.
I am using 8 m3.xlarge instances as worker nodes (8 vCore, 15 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage).

I have the following line of codes:

```
val userJobPredictionsDataset2 = userJobPredictionsDataset1.select($"userId", $"profile", explode($"notVisitedJobIds").as("notVisitedJobId"))
```

The `$"notVisitedJobIds"` column is an Array column. As a result, I think with my data the above `select` transformation with `explode` function can result in totally 30k * 30k rows (row number of Dataset1 * Array column size) in `userJobPredictionsDataset2`. The number of rows may be huge but the original data size of the `userJobPredictionsDataset1` is actually not large, it is about 100MB~200MB.

However the CPU consumption is high.
[image]

Also, it's been an hour and there's no completed `Task`s yet!
[image]

**Could you tell me what is the reason behind this slowliness?** **Is this slowliness normal considering the number of rows in the final `Dataset`?**

**Is there any way to solve this problem? Is it related to the number of partitions?**

Thanks!

Comment: its obvious to get slow if you have 30k elements in one notVisitedJobIds array in each row. Alternative solution really depends on what are your requirements for exploding

Comment: I want to `explode` it and then `join` with a job model `Dataset`, then compute the similarity between user profile and job model. So in each row there will be a user profile and a job model of which the similarity are to be computed in the final `Dataset` using a UDF.

Comment: So the count of rows is more impactful than the total size of original data when it comes to CPU usage?

Comment: You don't need to explode for that purpose. You can just join them and do the calculation parts defining a udf function. that would be much faster

Comment: its not exactly related to size of your data but the explode functions iterations that is taking the processing time

Comment: How `userJobPredictionsDataset1` data frame generated ? did you constructed using RDD?

Comment: `explode` was fixed in 2.3.0. Prior to the fix it had inefficient (and unnecessary) exponential complexity, as you see.

Comment: @RumeshKrish I did not use RDD. I totally used Dataset/DataFrame in this project. There are a series of transformation before `userJobPredictionsDataset1` is generated, some of which involve shuffle. To test my Spark program in a Zeppelin notebook, I have forced to execute the prior transformations considering the lazy ealuation feature, and those ones won't take more than afew mins. BTW I used `DatasetXXXX.rdd.count` to force the evaluation.

Comment: @shay__ Thanks a lot for the information. I am using Spark 2.2.1. So there are poblems with the `explode` function in Spark 2.2.1.

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领 please check in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657 if this is really your case (it might not be)

Comment: Yes, it is basically my problem. Previously I need to `explode` then `groupByKey` and `agg`. Now I "detoured" it and avoided using `explode`. I used a broadcast hash join since I actually can shrink the part of data that really need to be "joined". Then the broadcasted value and the computation all happen in a UDF which is called with a `select` on the original Dataset. I guess `explode` is not really designed in case there's too many elements in each `Row` to be exploded unless there's no other way.